# Routes and Controller problem on Codeigniter 4, can't access

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, controller

## Routes and Controller problem on Codeigniter 4, can't access

I created Controller and Routes, and I created a Navbar.php file in Controller with methods and GET in Routes, then can not be accessed with localhost CI. I need a solution because I'm just learning CI4, thank you.

This is the code.

Routes setting

```
// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/about', 'Navbar::about');
$routes->get('/contact', 'Navbar::contact');
$routes->get('/faqs', 'Navbar::faqs');
```

Navbar.php

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Page extends BaseController
{
    public function about()
    {
        echo "about page";
    }
    
    public function contact()
    {
        echo "contact page";
    }
    
    public function faqs()
    {
        echo "faqs page";
    }

}
```

I want to know where's error, need to problem solving with help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be change your **class name** in **Navbar.php** file where your controller name is **Navbar.php** but your class name is Page.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As your filename is **navbar.php**, class name must be **Navbar** with first capital letter.

navbar.php

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Navbar extends BaseController
{
   public function about()
   {
       echo "about page";
   }

   public function contact()
   {
      echo "contact page";
   }

   public function faqs()
   {
      echo "faqs page";
   }

}
```